# Electric Wire Color - Extractor Fan

Tags: electrical

I need to change the my extractor fan and it has three type of wires (seems old wiring). Refer attached picture for details. I believe Red is live but not clear about Green and Blue. In new extractor fan - it require only two inputs (Live and Neutral). I believe Red should go to live but not sure which color needs to go Neutral. please comment.[image]

Comment: Hard to tell from the picture.  It looks like the red wire is dead ended/not connected.  The wires for the fan motor(black) are connected to blue and yellow(your green?).  Might be connections behind the box, but right now looks like blue and yellow are live and neutral.  Your general location will help.

Comment: Thanks. @crip659. It is. Yellow is live and Blue and Neutral. All sorted. Thanks again.

Comment: If it was UK, I'd guess red = live, blue = neutral and yellow = earh. But, few clues...